# Header de tabla HTML estática o fijo

Tags: html-tabla

Quiero lograr que mi tabla HTML tenga un Header Fijo, pero hay un problema y es que tiene un scroll tanto en X como en Y... 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<table style="overflow: auto;width: 500px;height: 400px;">
<thead>
    <th>ENE</th>
    <th>FEB</th>
    <th>MAR</th>
    <th>ABR</th>
    <th>MAY</th>
    <th>JUN</th>
    <th>JUL</th>
    <th>AGO</th>
    <th>SEP</th>
    <th>OCT</th>
    <th>NOV</th>
    <th>DIC</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Contenido</td>
        <td>Contenido</td>
        <td>Contenido</td>
        <td>Contenido</td>
        <td>Contenido</td>
        <td>Contenido</td>
        <td>Contenido</td>
        <td>Contenido</td>
        <td>Contenido</td>
        <td>Contenido</td>
        <td>Contenido</td>
        <td>Contenido</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Contenido</td>
        <td>Contenido</td>
        <td>Contenido</td>
        <td>Contenido</td>
        <td>Contenido</td>
        <td>Contenido</td>
        <td>Contenido</td>
        <td>Contenido</td>
        <td>Contenido</td>
        <td>Contenido</td>
        <td>Contenido</td>
        <td>Contenido</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Contenido</td>
        <td>Contenido</td>
        <td>Contenido</td>
        <td>Contenido</td>
        <td>Contenido</td>
        <td>Contenido</td>
        <td>Contenido</td>
        <td>Contenido</td>
        <td>Contenido</td>
        <td>Contenido</td>
        <td>Contenido</td>
        <td>Contenido</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Contenido</td>
        <td>Contenido</td>
        <td>Contenido</td>
        <td>Contenido</td>
        <td>Contenido</td>
        <td>Contenido</td>
        <td>Contenido</td>
        <td>Contenido</td>
        <td>Contenido</td>
        <td>Contenido</td>
        <td>Contenido</td>
        <td>Contenido</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Contenido</td>
        <td>Contenido</td>
        <td>Contenido</td>
        <td>Contenido</td>
        <td>Contenido</td>
        <td>Contenido</td>
        <td>Contenido</td>
        <td>Contenido</td>
        <td>Contenido</td>
        <td>Contenido</td>
        <td>Contenido</td>
        <td>Contenido</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

es una tabla básica hecha solo con html y css pero necesitaría que cuando haga scroll tanto X como Y entonces este pueda quedar fijo en Y pero se mueva normalmente en X

Ya allí un ejemplo de una tabla. Lo que necesito es dejar el head fijo para que pese a que haga scroll en Y este se mantenga arriba, y si hace scrool en X entonces este muestre los demás meses.

Ojo utilizo un scroll en X debido a que no cabe completamente la tabla

He tratado ya con posicion absolute y fixed pero cuando hago esto se distorciona un poco la tabla y si hago scrool en X entonces queda estatico arriba osea quedan todos los meses pegados el uno del otro

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar tu código que lleves al momento?

Comment: Es dificil porque todo esta generado mediante for en PHP, pero es una tabla básica imagina que es una etiqueta Table otra Thead con los th y un Tbody con los tr es todo

Comment: Entiendo pero como sabes es importAnte agregues lo que lleves, puedes incluir el código de una tabla estática

Comment: Listo aunque como te dije una tabla básica

Answer (score 0):

Si continuamos usando html y css, sin recurrir a javascript ni librerías adicionales, para **fijar la cabecera de una tabla html**, quizás lo más sencillo sea aplicar un "[position](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/position)" adecuado (fixed o sticky) a la cabecera mediante css, como se ilustra en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
<!-- Ejemplo cabecera de tabla html fija usando position de CSS -->
<style>
#cabecera {
  padding: .5em .5em .5em 0em;
}
td {
  background-color: #eee;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
th {
  background-color: #222;
  color: white;
  padding: 2px;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 2px;
}
</style>

<div id="cabecera">Cabecera</div>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Título 1</th><th>Título 2</th><th>Título 3</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Contenido 1 - 0123456789</td><td>Contenido 2 - 0123456789</td><td>Contenido 3 - 0123456789</td></tr>
    <!-- ... Replicar líneas para ver efecto ... -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```